# Unsure about variable usage in javascript. (Photoshop scripting)

Tags: javascript, global-variables, photoshop-script

I'm having understanding when I can use my variables.
I am creating a script for photoshop and I declare the folowing variables:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var openDoc = app.documents;
var docNum = openDoc.length;
```

I then have a loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i < docNum; i++){
   //lots of code here
}
```

I try to use the doc variable for (below), placed inside the loop.  I'm given errors however, when I try to replace my app.activeDocument with my doc variable

```
app.activeDocument = app.documents[i]; 
app.activeDocument.selection.selectAll(); 
app.activeDocument.selection.copy();                            
app.activeDocument = app.documents[0]; 
app.activeDocument.activeLayer = app.activeDocument.layers["Layer 0"]; 
app.activeDocument.paste();
```

This must be a silly question to someone more experienced, I know there's something fundamental that I'm missing.

Edit:
Here are some of the errors I'm getting

```
doc = app.documents[i]; //alerts "selection is empty", logs "user cancelled the operation" line stoped at "...selection.copy(); "
doc.selection.selectAll(); //logs "the requested action requires that the target document is the frontmost document"
doc.selection.copy();  //same as previous                          
doc = app.documents[0]; //doesn't select the correct document, logs "no such element" stops at next line
app.activeDocument.activeLayer = app.activeDocument.layers["Layer 0"];
```

Comment: what's the error ? What line involved ?

Comment: The common one I get is "must be in the foreground".  I'll rerun it to write out the exact error, it's different each time I think.

Comment: And any of the "app.activeDocuments" that get replaced with my variable "doc" is the exact line that it stops at.

Comment: I may be off, but I presume that the problem is arising from what you are expecting your variables to represent. When you write `var doc = app.activeDocument;`, for example, you are saying the word "doc" is pointing to whatever my active document is right now. This does not mean, when you refer to "doc" later in your code, that it is the active document. "doc" still refers to the first document you pointed it at. Without seeing more of your code, I can't be sure, but perhaps setting doc to your active doc in the for loop could help.

Comment: Ohhh, that makes sense.  So it's like taking a snapshot.  I guess what's messing me up is that I'd be able to declare var doc = 5, and then later change it to doc = 7, no?

Comment: So does that mean if I wanted to reassign the doc variable, I could write doc = app.activeDocument (as long as my new active doc doesn't change)

Thank you, that must be it!

Comment: You may definitely set doc = 5 and then change it to doc = 7, but that has no effect on what the active doc is. Let's say doc =5 and doc is activeDoc, but then you open another document. That other document is now active doc. But doc is still 5. If you wanted to now change it to doc = 7, you would have to make it the active document again. Does that make any more sense?

Comment: The whole "doc = 5" is a really poor example for obvious reasons lol, but I think it makes it easier to see the issue you may be experiencing?